# release for objects on Class method?

Tags: objective-c

**Without using ARC**, for objects initialized using instance method we do release it via `release` call.

example:

```
Sample *obj = [[Sample alloc]init] ;
//   some code here
[obj release] ;
```

Now for objects allocated using **class methods** should `release` be called?

example:

```
TestSample *testobj = [TestSample initCustom] ;
// some code here
```

should there be `[testobj release]`?

Let's consider this standard function provided by apple.
`endpointWithHostname` is a class method.

```
NWHostEndpoint *pNetHost = [NWHostEndpoint endpointWithHostname:@"0.0.0.0" port:@"21"];
```

so, should there be a `[pNetHost release]` for above call?

Comment: You must not name a class method `initCustom`. Only a true initializer, i.e. something that follows `alloc`, should start with `init`. So rename `initCustom` properly; it should be called something like `testSample`. Now _show_ us the implementation of `testSample`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> for objects initialized using instance method we do release it via `release` call

The fact that you called an instance method isn’t relevant. You own any object returned by any method whose name starts with `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`. In your example, you called `alloc`, and therefore ownership has been transferred to you. That’s why you are now responsible for calling `release`.

However, if you called some instance method that didn’t start with one of those four prefixes, though, ownership would not be transferred to you, and you would not call `release`.

This is all summarized in the [Advance Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH), which says:

> #### Basic Memory Management Rules
>
> The memory management model is based on object ownership. Any object may have one or more owners. As long as an object has at least one owner, it continues to exist. If an object has no owners, the runtime system destroys it automatically. To make sure it is clear when you own an object and when you do not, Cocoa sets the following policy:
>
> - **You own any object you create**
>
>   You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, [`alloc`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LegacyTechnologies/WebObjects/WebObjects_3.5/Reference/Frameworks/ObjC/Foundation/Classes/NSObject/Description.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/alloc), [`newObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsobjectcontroller/1535921-newobject), or [`mutableCopy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LegacyTechnologies/WebObjects/WebObjects_3.5/Reference/Frameworks/ObjC/Foundation/Classes/NSObject/Description.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/mutableCopy)).
> - **You can take ownership of an object using retain**
>
>   A received object is normally guaranteed to remain valid within the method it was received in, and that method may also safely return the object to its invoker. You use `retain` in two situations: (1) In the implementation of an accessor method or an `init` method, to take ownership of an object you want to store as a property value; and (2) To prevent an object from being invalidated as a side-effect of some other operation (as explained in [Avoid Causing Deallocation of Objects You’re Using](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-1000922)).
> - **When you no longer need it, you must relinquish ownership of an object you own**
>
>   You relinquish ownership of an object by sending it a [`release`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LegacyTechnologies/WebObjects/WebObjects_3.5/Reference/Frameworks/ObjC/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject/Description.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/release) message or an [`autorelease`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LegacyTechnologies/WebObjects/WebObjects_3.5/Reference/Frameworks/ObjC/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject/Description.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/autorelease) message. In Cocoa terminology, relinquishing ownership of an object is therefore typically referred to as “releasing” an object.
> - **You must not relinquish ownership of an object you do not own**
>
>   This is just corollary of the previous policy rules, stated explicitly.

You go on to ask:

> let's consider this standard function provided by apple. `endpointWithHostname` is a class method.
>
> ```
>  NWHostEndpoint *pNetHost = [NWHostEndpoint endpointWithHostname:@"0.0.0.0" port:@"21"];
> ```
>
> so should there be a `[pNetHost release]` ; for above call

The fact that it is a class method isn’t relevant. The key is that the method name doesn’t start with `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`. That means that ownership has not been transferred to you and therefore you don’t need to call `release`. In this case, it is returning an autorelease object, so it will be released for you when the autoreleasepool is drained.

Obviously, if you want to claim ownership of the `pNetHost` object, you would do so by calling `retain` (and of course, at that point you’d then be responsible for eventually calling `release` to offset that `retain`).

---

Now, let’s consider your example:

> ```
> TestSample *testobj = [TestSample initCustom];
> // some code here
> ```
>
> should there be `[testobj release]`?

No. But let’s answer this question by looking at the implementation of the method you called `initCustom`. It might be implemented like so:

```
+ (instancetype)testSample {
    TestSample *obj = [[self alloc] init];

    // perhaps more customization of `obj` here

    return [obj autorelease];
}
```

But, there are two key observations in the above:

1. I didn’t start the method name with `init`. That prefix should only be used with initialization methods, which this method isn’t.

   The convention is to start the method name with the name of the object type, using camelCase (i.e. starting with a lowercase letter). Hence, this `TestSample` class method name might be called `testSample`, like above, not `initCustom`.
2. Because the method name doesn’t start with `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`, it should return an autorelease object. And because it is an `autorelease` object, the caller would therefore would not call `release` (unless, of course, it claimed ownership by calling `retain`).

---

By the way, the static analyzer (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>; or “Product” » “Analyze”) is exceptionally good at analyzing manual reference counting code.

For example, let’s imagine that I forgot to add the `autorelease` in the above `testSample` example. If I let Xcode analyze the code, the compiler would tell me about the problem:

[image]

If I add the `autorelease` back in and re-analyze, this warning will go away.

When writing manual reference counting code, the static analyzer is an invaluable tool. Always make sure you have a clean bill of health from the analyzer.

Comment: That is a detailed answer . thank you . j
just a follow up : for new programs is it suggested to use ARC or we must avoid that ?

Comment: Use ARC. Memory management is hard enough without introducing the idiosyncrasies of manual reference counting. Manual reference counting is a bit of an anachronism at this point. (And if you're debating Swift or Objective-C, most developers are using Swift for new projects.)